# Android: Call IntentService from NotificationManager action PendingIntent

Tags: android, intentservice, notificationmanager

I have a push notification app.
When the push notification comes, the BroadcastReceiver calls GCMIntentService to setup notification

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddToCalendarIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(JSON_KEY_CLASS_ID, classid);
        intent.putExtra(JSON_KEY_CLASS_NAME, classname);
        intent.putExtra(Config.JSON_KEY_DATE, tgl);
        intent.putExtra(Config.JSON_KEY_TIME_START, timestart);
        intent.putExtra(Config.JSON_KEY_TIME_END, timeend);
        intent.putExtra(Config.JSON_KEY_VENUE, venue);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, classid + ", " + classname + ", " + venue);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
                        .setContentTitle("Re: " + classname)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(pesan))
                        .setContentText(pesan)
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_add_person, "Add to Calendar", contentIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setTicker("Reschedule Class");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

When user click on the Add to Calendar, it invoke PendingIntent to start AddToCalendarIntentService with all the parameter.

```
public class AddToCalendarIntentService extends IntentService {

public AddToCalendarIntentService() {
    super("AddToCalendarIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final String JSON_KEY_CLASS_NAME = "classname";
    final String JSON_KEY_CLASS_ID = "classid";
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    String title = extra.getString(JSON_KEY_CLASS_NAME);
    String location = extra.getString(Config.JSON_KEY_VENUE);
    String tgl = extra.getString(Config.JSON_KEY_DATE);
    String[] tglSplit = tgl.split("-");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(tglSplit[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(tglSplit[1]);
    int date = Integer.parseInt(tglSplit[2]);

    String timestart = extra.getString(Config.JSON_KEY_TIME_START);
    String timeend = extra.getString(Config.JSON_KEY_TIME_END);
    String[] start = timestart.split(":");
    String[] end = timeend.split(":");
    int hourStart = Integer.parseInt(start[0]);
    int minStart = Integer.parseInt(start[1]);
    int hourEnd = Integer.parseInt(end[0]);
    int minEnd = Integer.parseInt(end[1]);
    Log.d("INTENT SERVICE", location);
    TaskHelper.addToCalendar(this, "Reschedule: " + title, location, year, month-1, date, hourStart, minStart, hourEnd, minEnd);
    NotificationManager mNotification = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotification.cancel(1);
}
}
```

The code works, but if I got the other notification again, and Added it to calendar, the parameter in AddToCalendarIntentService keep the old parameter, ignoring the new one.
For example, in the first the location is *Indonesia*, both **GCMIntentService** and **AddToCalendarIntentService** log show *Indonesia*.

In the 2nd notification, the location is *Singapore*, it show correctly in **GCMIntentService**, but when logging in **AddToCalendarIntentService**, it show *Indonesia* (It should be Singapore).

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: read the docs about second param of getService()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the system thinks its the same PendingIntent, if you want to have a couple of pending intents you need to differentiate them.

The easiest way is to supply different requestCodes (the 2nd parameters of PendingIntent.getService).

You can read more about it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 1):

As TomerZ pointed out, the system thinks its the same PendingIntent.
Add the Flag: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to your pending intent to inform the system to update the extras of the pending intent.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

[The documentation of the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT for reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)